# apache .htaccess error 500

Tags: apache2, php

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I configured the `.htaccess` file in the restful project, but I got error 500, internal server error. Without the `.htaccess` file the application works. I changed apache to:

[image: apache view]

`.htaccess` file contents:

[image: htaccess view]

Comment: Is this the exact text of the .htaccess file? because it looks like it's missing some `>` and has some extra `<br>`, `;`, some capitals where there should be lowercase. Fix your formatting.

Comment: Try to remove the first and last line from your `.htaccess` file and then look at apache's error log.

Comment: What does `/var/log/apache2/error.log` say?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots into your question. Simply copy and paste the text and use the code formatter button.

Answer (score 0):

New contents of the .htaccess file:

[image: .htaccess view]

Now my restful is working fine.